# What happens when I use up all my lives?

Tags: 1001-spikes

1001 Spikes starts you with 1001 lives. What are the consequences of using up all my lives before reaching the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run out of lives, you get three more added to the total. You don't lose progress or have to start over at all. So technically, your number of lives for all practical purposes is infinite.